# Let Y be a proper closed subspace of a normed linear space X...

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, normed-spaces

I bought a book called "Problems in Real and Functional Analysis" because it contained solutions.  There is one problem I couldn't quite convince myself of, but when I looked for the solution it was missing:

**Problem 8.30.** Let $Y$ be a proper closed subspace of a normed linear space $X$. Prove

$$ \sup_{0 \neq x \in X} \frac{d(x,Y)}{||x||} = 1 $$

**Attempt:**
Case 1: If $x \in Y$ then $d(x,Y)=0$ and $\frac{d(x,Y)}{||x||} = 0 \leq 1$.

Case 2: If $x \in X\backslash Y$ then $d(x,Y)>0$ because $Y$ is closed. Thus for some $y \in Y$ we have $ d(x,Y)= ||x-y|| $.

Suppose $x-y \in Y$ then $\exists y_0 \in Y$ such that $x-y=y_0$ but then $x=y_0 + y$ which contradicts the closure of $Y$. Therefore $x-y \in X\backslash Y$ and so $\exists x_0 \in X\backslash Y$ such that $x-y = x_0$ or in other words $x=x_0 +y$ and $-y = x_0 -x $. Clearly $x_0$ is nonzero because $0 \in Y$. Then

$\frac{d(x,Y)}{||x||} =  \frac{ ||x-y||}{||x||} = \frac{||x +(x_0 - x)||}{||x_0 +y||} = \frac{||x_0||}{||x_0 + y||} \leq 0$

For this fixed $y$ get a sequence $x_n$ in $X\backslash Y$ such that $d(x_n,Y) = ||x_n-y||$ as well as $||x_n-y||< ||x_{n+1} - y ||$ (can I assume this?). For each $x_n-y$ we can say $x_n - y  = x_0^n$ for some $x_0^n \in X$. Notice $||x_0^n|| < ||x_0^{n+1}||$ as well. Then

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{||x_0^n||}{||x_0^n + y||}=1 $$

and hence

$$ \sup_{0 \neq x \in X} \frac{d(x,Y)}{||x||} = 1 $$

Comment: Clearly one needs to assume that$x \notin Y$.

Comment: In your case 2, why does "clearly $d(x, Y) = \|x - y\|$"? I mean, $Y$ is not compact (it can't be), so it is not so clearly I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $d(x + y, Y) = d(x, Y)$ for $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$.  For $x \in X \setminus Y$,  and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $y \in Y$ such that
$$
||x + y|| (1 - \epsilon) < d(x, Y), 
$$
so
$$
1 - \epsilon < \frac{d(x, Y)}{||x + y||} = \frac{d(x', Y)}{||x'||},
$$
with $x' = x + y$.
Thus, more exactly than the original statement, for any given $x \in X \setminus Y$
$$
1 = \sup\{ \frac{d(x', Y)}{||x'||} : x' \in x + Y\}.
$$